# Embedding a terminal Window inside of a simple scala application

Tags: java, swing, bash, scala

I'm trying to build a simple text editor using Scala's swing library and I have to support two side by side windows. I was wondering if it was possible to have the second window be the terminal (bash, Unix). I haven't been able to find any information on the subject. Thank you for any information.

Comment: Somebody has to know something on the subject. I haven't been able to find any information still.

Answer (score 0):

The question is: What is "the terminal"? `bash` is a shell but you need an implementation of a terminal which runs a certain shell. In general, I would say there are two possibilities:

1. Find a terminal implementation, which can be used directly in Swing. Maybe you [this](http://code.google.com/p/gritty/) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179329/importing-a-terminal-into-swing-application) may help.
2. Implement your own terminal. You may want to start to wrap the shell with a `ProcessBuilder`. Now you can redirect standard input and output of this process so that you can control it programmatically (more information: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376925/run-interactive-command-line-application-from-java) and [there](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html)). Then you have to create the UI part which (1) reads input from the user and (2) displays the shell output in your window.