# How to run a .bat file with pause and proceed in java

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a utility which processes multiple csv files. The actual scenario is:

1. Run the .bat file.
2. When file1.csv is processed, .bat file is paused and shows us the option to verify the output and press enter to continue with file2.csv.
3. Like wise it goes for multiple files.

Now I need to automate this process of executing .bat file with pause and proceed. Currently, I can execute the .bat file in below way:

```
String cmd = "cmd /c run.bat");
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
p.waitFor();
```

Kindly help with pause and proceed option.

EDIT: While at Pause, I call a sub thread to verify the output(currently working with verifying the output automatically). Say if the output was TRUE, then I need to proceed with .bat file or else, terminate.

Comment: Would be reasonable, for you, just adding pause command in the tail of the bat file?

Comment: @Cubo78 the order of processing csv files is dependent. With completion of each file, we verify the output manually and then press ENTER to proceed with the next file.

Comment: Modify `run.bat` to optionally not pause on batch file called with a parameter like `/nopause` by modifying in batch file the line `pause` to `if /I not "%~1" == "/nopause" pause` and use in Java code `"cmd.exe /c run.bat /nopause"`.

Comment: If your process needs to interact with the user, I think a GUI application would be more appropriate. If it needs to be totally automatic with no need for user interaction, why not just translate all the batch file processing to java code. If your batch processing uses Windows API, consider writing your app in C# or C++ so that you can easily utilize the Windows API. If it must be written only in java then consider [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna).

Comment: [run interactive command line application from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376925/run-interactive-command-line-application-from-java)

Comment: ...maybe just a typo here, but there are unbalanced parentheses in the first line of code...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short POC according to ur needs . You can modify it.

.bat file

```js
@echo off
@echo hi 
@echo File 1 underReview
@echo Press 0 to continue
PAUSE
@echo Done Review..
PAUSE
```

Java File BatchAutomateInput

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "BATInput.bat");
    File dir = new File("C:\\BatTest");
    pb.directory(dir);
    Process p = pb.start();
    InputStream out = p.getInputStream();   
    OutputStream outConsole=p.getOutputStream();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(out));
        //BufferedWriter bout = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outConsole)); 
        PrintWriter bout = new PrintWriter( p.getOutputStream() );
        String line = null;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.trim().length() > 0) {
                System.out.println(line);
                if(line.contains("Press 0"))
                {
                    int i=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                    bout.write(i);
                    bout.write("\n");
                    bout.flush();
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Executed Sucessfully");


}
```

Output Java Console

```html
hi 
File 1 underReview
Press 0 to continue
0
Press any key to continue . . . 
Done Review..
Press any key to continue . . . 
Executed Sucessfully
```

Comment: I have modified my question. I need to proceed after a pause when a certain condition is met.

Comment: As u can see we can  send input of any number/String .So from java if condition is true then in bout.write(i) send 0 else send 1.Using this,suppose 1 is for terminate ,In your bat file if u get 1 then **exit** from it else continue. Getting my point?

Comment: `@echo off
@echo hi 
@echo File 1 underReview
@echo Press 0 to continue or 1 to terminate
set /P val="Validation"
IF "%val%"== "0" (
    ECHO found
)
Exit`